# Android RecyclerView setScrollPosition() delay issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with 30 items totally, 10 items are visible on the screen. I want to use `setScrollPosition()` to scroll the `RecyclerView`

But when I pass a value, 
For Example: `setScrollPosition(5)`, the `RecyclerView` is not getting scrolled by 5 items. But the scrolling initiates when I pass value 10 or above.

What is the reason for that delay? 
Is that because the `RecyclerView` offset is at the `lastVisiblePosition`? 
How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say you have 30 items in your `RecyclerView` and if you want to scroll to `15th`position you can simply use `scrollToPosition()` function to scroll to that particular position.

And if you want to scroll by 5 positions and you have used `LinearLayoutManager`, then you can do this :

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = (LinearLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
int lastPos = llm.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(lastPos + 5);
```

Comment: I tried this already and it works fine. But what i want is, if i do scrollToPosition(2) then item2 should come to the top. I am able to achive this kind of scrolling in ListView. Is there any way to achieve it in RecyclerView?

Comment: If you want item2 at top then use llm.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2,0)

Comment: Yes. I got it. Thank You.